# Need help in codeigniter url

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

I developed a website in Codeigniter, but it appends a hash string at the end of every url.

For example:

```
http://my_website.com/#.UR46O6Wj12I
```

I want to remove this hash string after every url or preventing it from being appended to the url.

Comment: Does this happen when you turn of javascript in your browser too?

Comment: That isn't CI doing that, it's sharethis.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have also posted this question at ellislab, so I checked out your page through there. The problem lies in your javascript, not in codeigniter.

The code causing the hash is this in your html:

```
<div class="like_social">
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
   <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
      <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" style="width:75px; overflow:none"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_tweet" style="width:80px;overflow:none"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_linkedin_counter" style="width:100px;overflow:none"></a> 
      <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:annotation="bubble"></a> 
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5112601232209e07"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>
```

Like Rick Calder suggested, it's from some sort of an add-on, in this case a button from **AddThis**. More info from their [support documentation](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics) can be found regarding that hash.

If you want to still keep that button, it seems that you can disable it by going to the advanced tab of the AddThis settings page and unchecking the **Track address bar shares**.

Alternatively, you can set `data_track_addressbar` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

please put this code end of the index file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
                addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
</script>
```

if you use tpl ddon forget `{literal}this code{/literal}`
this will helpfull